# How to import third party librarys (npm packages) in Ionic 4?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

since a couple of things have changed in Ionic 4, I would like to know a definit guid on how to implement third party libs, such as "rss-parser".

I do have read this article, as it turns out to be the latest to this topic: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/third-party-libs/

but it did not help.

Here is what I did so far:

```
npm install --save rss-parser
```

Than I tried nearly everthing:

- Referencing the rss-parser.min.js inside my index.html,
- Using varieties of `declare module` and `declare var`
- Trying to do the standard `import {} from 'rss-parser'`, as Ionic 4 uses `es2015/Typescript` or later

Here is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Services
import { DataService } from './data-service.service';
//import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule/*, InAppBrowser */ ],
  providers: [
    DataService,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And here is my `tab1.page.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data-service.service'
import { Parser } from 'rss-parser/lib/parser.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor( private dataService: DataService )
    {
    console.log( "Parser: ", Parser );
    }
```

Now I have a couple of questions:

- When I have a link to a node package repo like
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser, how do I know, "what to
  import" ?

For example I searched the `rss-parser/index.js` which required `./lib/parser`, which then got `class Parser {}`. I assume, that is, where we have to look, what to import?

So I used the following code:

```
import { Parser }  from 'rss-parser/dist/rss-parser.js';
declare var Parser: any;

console.log( "Parser: ", Parser );
```

and it gives me the following error message:

```
Tab1Page_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR ReferenceError: Parser is not defined
    at new Tab1Page (tab1.page.ts:20)
    at createClass (core.js:22142)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:22019)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:23245)
    at createRootView (core.js:23159)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24167)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:23677)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:21498)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:9934)
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:21609)


View_Tab1Page_Host_0 @ Tab1Page_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:18234
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:24129
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15762
(anonymous) @ core.js:18116
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17248
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:18116
(anonymous) @ core.js:18000
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:17289
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:17203
next @ core.js:18000
schedulerFn @ core.js:13505
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13489
checkStable @ core.js:17258
onHasTask @ core.js:17302
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:879
resolvePromise @ zone.js:825
(anonymous) @ zone.js:741
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ tab1-tab1-module.js:1
Tab1Page_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 1, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
View_Tab1Page_Host_0 @ Tab1Page_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
proxyClass @ compiler.js:18234
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:24129
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15767
(anonymous) @ core.js:18116
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17248
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:18116
(anonymous) @ core.js:18000
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:17289
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:17203
next @ core.js:18000
schedulerFn @ core.js:13505
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13489
checkStable @ core.js:17258
onHasTask @ core.js:17302
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:413
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:879
resolvePromise @ zone.js:825
(anonymous) @ zone.js:741
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ tab1-tab1-module.js:1
core.js:15714 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Parser is not defined


ReferenceError: Parser is not defined
    at new Tab1Page (tab1.page.ts:20)
    at createClass (core.js:22142)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:22019)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:23245)
    at createRootView (core.js:23159)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24167)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:23677)
    at ComponentFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:21498)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:9934)
    at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.js:21609)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Any help with this? Maybe a step by step guid, on how to import third party npm's in Ionic 4, which - according to the internet - would help a lot of people.

**Edit:**
Obviously NOT a possible duplicate of [Convert XML RSS feed to Json on Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840193/convert-xml-rss-feed-to-json-on-angular-app), because I want to know how to implement third party node packages into Ionic 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840193/convert-xml-rss-feed-to-json-on-angular-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert XML RSS feed to Json on Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840193/convert-xml-rss-feed-to-json-on-angular-app)

Comment: The `dist` directory contains files generated for direct use in the browser. Maybe you need this syntax: https://github.com/bobby-brennan/rss-parser#web

The earlier answer was wrong, so I deleted it.

Comment: But where to put the `<script></script>` tags, since ionic 4 has no reference to `polyfill.js`. However, `polyfill.js` is needed **after** importing the Script-Element.

Answer (score 0):

i have an issue with this package too with ionic4,

(as i explain herre https://github.com/bobby-brennan/rss-parser/issues/109 )

i haven't found a workaround yet, it seems that the rss-parser package is not compatible with new ECMAScript module.

benji7425 is saying that here

https://github.com/bobby-brennan/rss-parser/issues/98

with tofra  github test project here

https://github.com/tofra/angular-rss-parser/issues/1

For the script tag you can put it in the index.html file after all other script tag :)